# Display the PPID in the system monitor?

Tags: kde

Is it possible to display the PPID (parent process ID) in the process table of ksysguard ? There's no option for it when I right-click on bar up top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see the parent's PID if you use the tree mode and/or if you move the mouse cursor over the process.

[image]